# How to use RCPP_ARMADILLO_RETURN_ANYVEC_AS_VECTOR in an R package?

Tags: r, rcpp, rcpparmadillo

How do I use `RCPP_ARMADILLO_RETURN_ANYVEC_AS_VECTOR` in an R package?

File `veccany_as_v_test.cpp`:

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
#define RCPP_ARMADILLO_RETURN_ANYVEC_AS_VECTOR
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::vec veccany_as_v_test(const arma::vec& v) { return(v); }
```

Reprex:

```
x <- 1 : 5

Rcpp::sourceCpp("veccany_as_v_test.cpp")

# as expected
veccany_as_v_test(x)
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5

# create basic package
RcppArmadillo::RcppArmadillo.package.skeleton("veccany")
file.copy("veccany_as_v_test.cpp", to = "veccany/src/veccany_as_v_test.cpp")
Rcpp::compileAttributes("veccany")
install.packages("veccany", repos = NULL, type = "source")

# not as expected
veccany::veccany_as_v_test(x)
#     [,1]
#[1,]    1
#[2,]    2
#[3,]    3
#[4,]    4
#[5,]    5
```

Output `sessionInfo()`:

```
R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31)
Platform: aarch64-apple-darwin20 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Ventura 13.2.1

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/lib/libRblas.0.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] C/UTF-8/C/C/C/C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.2.2           tools_4.2.2              RcppArmadillo_0.12.0.1.0
[4] Rcpp_1.0.10              veccany_1.0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to ensure it is set *before each #include* of `RcppArmadillo`. One way to ensure that is via `-D...` in `src/Makevars`.  (The trick is we also need to have the effect on `src/RcppExports.cpp`.  There is custom way via an include file -- but using `-D...` is easier.)

Simple and quick example:

##### Create a package.

We can call `RcppArmadillo.package.skeleton()`. I use a handy wrapper from my `littler` package.

```
$ kitten.r --type arma armademo
```

##### Modify the file(s)

Here I edit `src/rcpparma_hello_world.cpp`, and for good measure I include your `vecany()` function source code.

Remember to add `PKG_CPPFLAGS=-DRCPP_ARMADILLO_RETURN_ANYVEC_AS_VECTOR` in `src/Makevars` (and `src/Makevars.win` for Windows).

##### Build and install

Remember to call `compileAttributes()` (when adding / altering a function (interface)), and then install it. You should see the `-D...` on the compilation line.

##### Test it

```
$ Rscript -e 'armademo:::veccany_as_v_test(c(2,3,4,42,99))'
[1]  2  3  4 42 99
$
```

I will commit this in a minute to my [code from stackoverflow answers repo](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/stackoverflow) so you have the full example there. [Done.  Files are [here](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/stackoverflow/tree/master/75560370).]

Comment: Thank you very much for the swift and detailed answer. The `-D` flag in `Makevars` did the trick. Accepting this answer.

Comment: It's a good question as the impact of `RcppExport.cc` -- where the _actual return to R happens_ is not-obvious.